# Creating a responsive circular header with SVG shapes

Tags: html, css, svg, responsive-design

I am trying to make a semicircular/oval shaped header that is responsive along with the content inside it. Right now it only really looks fine on desktop and I really have no clue how to get it to look correct on mobile or when the window gets resized.

The problem is that on zoom out the visible part of the circle gets too thin at the top and almost disappears, leaving the content of the header now outside of the shape, and on zoom in (and on mobile devices/smaller screens) the circle just gets ridiculously huge and the image in the svg doesnt fill the header shape anymore.

Thanks for your help.

Ideally the header should look like this:

[image: Ideally the header should look like this]

And on mobile instead of looking like this

[image: this]

something more like this:

[image: this]

Here is another issue of it which i exaggerated by zooming out a lot:

[image: another issue]

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/150dr2bb/27/

and here is all the code needed to reproduce this:

HTML:

```
<header>
  <div id="headercirclecont" style="text-align:center;">
    <svg id="headerwhitecircle" preserverAspectRatio="none">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
          <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#7c3495;stop-opacity:1" />
          <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#f3366a;stop-opacity:1" />
        </linearGradient>
        <clipPath id="circleView">
          <circle cx="50vw" cy="-20vh" r="790px"/>            
        </clipPath>
      </defs>

      <circle cx="50vw" cy="-20vh" r="800px" fill="white" /> 
      <circle cx="50vw" cy="-20vh" r="790px" fill="url(#grad1)" /> 
      <image id="circleflimage" width="100vw" opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg/1200px-Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"/>
    </svg>  
  </div>

  <div id="headercontent">
    <div id="headerparent">
      <div>
        <h1 id="logo" class="whitetext">
          Test
        </h1>
      </div> 
      <br>
      <div id="headsocials">
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
        <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
html{
  margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body{
  background: #161925;
    height: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    font-family: "moon2reg", "latolight", "calibri", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

header {
  height: 700px;
  max-height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#headerwhitecircle {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 700px;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;
  width: 100%;
}

#headercirclecont {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#circleflimage {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 100vw;
  max-height: 700px;
}

#headercontent {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 700px;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items:center;

}

#headerparent {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#headsocials {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: flex;
}

p.svgsocials {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

p.svgsocials:after {
  content: ""; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  left: 0;
}

h1 {
  color: #161925;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-family: moon2reg calibri;
}

p {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 5px;
}

.whitetext {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.centertext {
  text-align: center;
}

#titleTxt {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you elaborate a bit more regarding what you are trying to achieve? Do you want exactly what in your picture above but to be responsive and to keep proportions etc?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I have edited my post with additional images. The main issue really is that the content always stays inside some form of the semicircle and doesnt end up outside, as well as the opposite of that where the header semicircle gets so huge that it becomes bigger than the screen.

Comment: I meant the key thing im trying to achieve, and the main issue being the rest of what i wrote after.

Comment: Clear ty, i can look into this later tonight if no one helps by that time. Thing is that you combine vector (scales well) and raster (pixel based) and ideally you want vector everything (like icons) to achieve good responsiveness

Comment: @SergeyRudenko my icons are all vectors too, the only thing that isnt vector is the logo with the 2 white raindrops on the sides, and the pretty transparent background image.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may have complicated things for yourself here by trying to control the behaviour of the SVG using units like `vw` and `vh`, rather than using an SVG  `viewBox` and taking advantage of SVG's built-in responsiveness features.

When you switch to a `viewBox` everything becomes a lot simpler and easier.

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/150dr2bb/58/

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
html{line-height:1.15;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}body{margin:0}h1{font-size:2em;margin:.67em 0}hr{box-sizing:content-box;height:0;overflow:visible}pre{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}a{background-color:transparent}abbr[title]{border-bottom:none;text-decoration:underline;text-decoration:underline dotted}b,strong{font-weight:bolder}code,kbd,samp{font-family:monospace,monospace;font-size:1em}small{font-size:80%}sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;vertical-align:baseline}sub{bottom:-.25em}sup{top:-.5em}img{border-style:none}button,input,optgroup,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;line-height:1.15;margin:0}button,input{overflow:visible}button,select{text-transform:none}button,[type="button"],[type="reset"],[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button}button::-moz-focus-inner,[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner{border-style:none;padding:0}button:-moz-focusring,[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring{outline:1px dotted ButtonText}fieldset{padding:.35em .75em .625em}legend{box-sizing:border-box;color:inherit;display:table;max-width:100%;padding:0;white-space:normal}progress{vertical-align:baseline}textarea{overflow:auto}[type="checkbox"],[type="radio"]{box-sizing:border-box;padding:0}[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button{height:auto}[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;outline-offset:-2px}[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none}::-webkit-file-upload-button{-webkit-appearance:button;font:inherit}details{display:block}summary{display:list-item}template{display:none}[hidden]{display:none}

    html{
      margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0 !important;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    body{
      background: #161925;
        height: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        font-family: "moon2reg", "latolight", "calibri", sans-serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 17px;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 1600px;
      position: relative;
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      justify-content:center;
      align-items:center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    #headercirclecont {
      display: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    #headerwhitecircle {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 250px;
      max-height: 700px;
    }

    #headercontent {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 100%;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center; 
    }

    #headerparent {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #logo {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 600px;
      z-index: 1;
    }

    #headsocials {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40px;
      display: flex;
    }

    p.svgsocials {
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    p.svgsocials:after {
      content: ""; 
      position: absolute; 
      top: 0; 
      right: 0; 
      bottom: 0; 
      left: 0;
    }

    h1 {
      color: #161925;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 80px;
        font-weight: 100;
        font-family: moon2reg calibri;
    }

    p {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 30px;
      margin: 5px;
    }

    .whitetext {
      color: #ffffff;
    }

    .centertext {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #titleTxt {
      height: 100%;
      max-height: 60px;
    }
```

```html
<header>
      <div id="headercirclecont" style="text-align:center;">
        <svg id="headerwhitecircle" viewBox="0 0 1600 700" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice">
          <defs>
            <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
              <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:#7c3495;stop-opacity:1" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:#f3366a;stop-opacity:1" />
            </linearGradient>
            <clipPath id="circleView">
              <circle cx="800" cy="-100" r="790px"/>            
            </clipPath>
          </defs>

          <circle cx="800" cy="-100" r="800px" fill="white" /> 
          <circle cx="800" cy="-100" r="790px" fill="url(#grad1)" /> 
          <image id="circleflimage" width="1600" height="700" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" 
                 opacity="0.1" xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg/1200px-Phinizy_swamp_nature_park_floodplain_in_hdr.jpg" clip-path="url(#circleView)"/>
        </svg>  
      </div>

      <div id="headercontent">
        <div id="headerparent">
          <div>
            <h1 id="logo" class="whitetext">
              Test
            </h1>
          </div> 
          <br>
          <div id="headsocials">
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
            <p class="svgsocials">a</p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it has helped a lot. One issue I have now is the content inside the header looks like [this](https://i.imgur.com/iqqmoZx.png) on mobile in landscape, but it looks fine in portrait.

Comment: You could use a media query to adjust the font sizes of the content for screens that aren't very high.